# I want the program to execute that when i click any first switch enable popup message should not be shown

Tags: laravel

I don't want to show popup message when i click to enable first any checkbox popup message should not be shown `product is already feature!` i have already made if condition for enable switch button, except any first switch  i want to show popup message  please help me how can i do that ?

please check image
https://ibb.co/QdFCd3z

i have made condition when i click to any switch enable message should be showing but now i want that when i click to any first switch enable popup message shouls not be shown

```
if(is_featured == true) {
      swal({
        text: "Product is already featured!",
        type: 'error',     
       })  
    }
```

**controller**

```
public function featured(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->is_featured) {

            $assignFeature = Product::where('is_featured', 1)->exists();
            if ($assignFeature) {
                $response['message'] = 'Product is already featured';
                return response()->json($response, 404);
            }
        }
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $featured = $request->input('is_featured');
        $featurediItem = Product::find($id);
        if ($featurediItem->update(['is_featured' => $featured])) {

            // form helpers.php
            logAction($request);

            $response['is_featured'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'product featured updated successfully.';
            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }
    }
```

**ajax script**

```
     $('.postfeatured').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.val();
    var is_featured = this.checked;
    if (is_featured) {
      is_featured = 1;
    } else {
      is_featured = 0;
    }
    if(is_featured == true) {
      swal({
        text: "Product is already featured!",
        type: 'error',     
       })  
    }
    axios
      .post('{{route("product.featured")}}', {
        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
        _method: 'patch',
        id: id,
        is_featured: is_featured,
      }) 
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
       
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);    
    });
  });
```

Comment: what is output of  var is_featured = this.checked;   code of line

Comment: is_featured give me .     true or false

Comment: kindly shere response of is_featured

Comment: {"is_featured":true,"message":"product featured updated successfully."}

Comment: https://ibb.co/BjZbqwV

Comment: You must differnaite your switch with id's this time each switch contain same class due to this you are facing issue. its because first switch is true and same class asign to all switchs